# How do I stop the scroll function when a selector is clicked?

Tags: jquery, html, css

The individual parent menu items in the navigation will become highlighted when the corresponding section on that page is scrolled to.

Now, if a visitor decides to click a parent menu item instead of scroll, the parent menu items doesn't correctly highlight because the scroll function follows and highlights the previous parent menu item.

How do I stop the scroll function from firing after $('.nav a) is clicked?

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  var services = $('.services').offset().top;
  var locations = $('.locations').offset().top;
  var about = $('.about').offset().top;
  var contact = $('.contact').offset().top;

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    if (scrollPos >= services && scrollPos < locations) {
      $('.nav a').removeClass('active');
      $('.wsite-nav-2 a').addClass('active');
    } else if (scrollPos >= locations && scrollPos < about) {
      $('.nav a').removeClass('active');
      $('.wsite-nav-3 a').addClass('active');
    } else if (scrollPos >= about && scrollPos < contact) {
      $('.nav a').removeClass('active');
      $('.wsite-nav-4 a').addClass('active');
    } else if (scrollPos >= contact) {
      $('.nav a').removeClass('active');
      $('.wsite-nav-5 a').addClass('active');
    } else if (scrollPos <= services) {
      $('.nav a').removeClass('active');
      $('.wsite-nav-1 a').addClass('active');
    }
  });

  $('.wsite-nav-1 a').addClass('active');

  $('.nav a').click(function() {
    $('.nav a, .wsite-nav-1 a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });

});
```

```css
.active {
  background: #f0b823;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="wsite-nav-1"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="wsite-nav-2"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li class="wsite-nav-3"><a href="#">Locations</a></li>
    <li class="wsite-nav-4"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li class="wsite-nav-5"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <div class="anchor">
    <a name="A" class="anchor-link services"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="anchor">
    <a name="B" class="anchor-link locations"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="anchor">
    <a name="C" class="anchor-link about"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="anchor">
    <a name="D" class="anchor-link contact"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: shortcut is to declare a flag variable set it to false initially and keep checking  in scroll function if it is false, on clicking switch that to true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might do something like this for quick fix.

```js
var isClicked = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {

  if (isClicked) {
    return false;
  }

  var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
  if (scrollPos >= services && scrollPos < locations) {
    $('.nav a').removeClass('active');
    $('.wsite-nav-2 a').addClass('active');
  } else if (scrollPos >= locations && scrollPos < about) {
    $('.nav a').removeClass('active');
    $('.wsite-nav-3 a').addClass('active');
  } else if (scrollPos >= about && scrollPos < contact) {
    $('.nav a').removeClass('active');
    $('.wsite-nav-4 a').addClass('active');
  } else if (scrollPos >= contact) {
    $('.nav a').removeClass('active');
    $('.wsite-nav-5 a').addClass('active');
  } else if (scrollPos <= services) {
    $('.nav a').removeClass('active');
    $('.wsite-nav-1 a').addClass('active');
  }
});

$('.wsite-nav-1 a').addClass('active');

$('.nav a').click(function() {
  isClicked = true;
  $('.nav a, .wsite-nav-1 a').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

### Update:

This was the accepted solution for this question - https://codepen.io/bb027/pen/VMQdXL

Comment: So close, @Blackburn027! I implemented your recommendation, but now when I scroll after clicking, the scroll function doesn't work.

Comment: How do I stop the scroll function from firing after $('.nav a) is clicked? This was your question.

Comment: https://codepen.io/bb027/pen/VMQdXL Check this snippet and let me know if this is how you want it to work

Comment: Nope, you're correct -- my initial question was not clear enough. Regardless, your second solution did it! Thank you very much for your time, @BlackBurn027!

Comment: Glad i could help (y)